# htaccess redirect from folder to subfolder in all my pages

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

How can I htaccess redirect

from:

`/folder/subforlder/pdf`
`/folder1/subforlder1/pdf`
`/folder2/subforlder2/pdf`

to:
`/folder/subforlder`
`/folder1/subforlder1`
`/folder2/subforlder2`

just to delete /pdf in all my pages!

Answer (score 0):

You may do the following in your .htaccess file.

Redirect /folder/subforlder/pdf "single space" /folder/subforlder

Redirect /folder1/subforlder1/pdf "single space" /folder1/subforlder1

Redirect /folder2/subforlder2/pdf "single space" /folder2/subforlder2

Comment: Yeah.. but I have more than 1000 pages.. Need smth universal =)

Answer (score 0):

To match and rewrite all Uris ending on `/pdf` use the following RewriteRule. This just kills the `/pdf` on all your routes.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/pdf$
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: I don't know but nothing happened with this string. Pages stay at the same destination. Any other ideas? =)

Comment: I think you area missing `RewriteEngine On`, I'll edit my answer.